# Open File From Partially Qualified Path in Perl

Tags: perl

For an introductory web scripting class, I am working on a project written in Perl that deals with reading a file on the server.  I need to collect a filename, open it, do some regex matching on the contents, and output results.

The filename input can come in multiple forms:

- "file.txt"
- "/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/file.txt"
- "dir3/dir4/file.txt"

The first two cases work with a simple call to open:

```
...
$file = param('file');
open(FH, "<", $file) || die "Cannot open $file: $!";
while (<FH>) {
    # do stuff
}
...
```

The last case with the partially qualified path obviously dies.  I looked at File::Find, but can't quite figure out how it works.  Is that the right module for me to use?  Should I be doing some sort of recursive thing to work backwards through the directory tree?  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Edit:
My case is very specific to instructions given by my professor.  I got it working through a loop:

```
...
$file = param('file');
$open = open (FH, "<", $file);
while (!defined $open) {
    chdir('..') or die "Can't chdir or open $file $!";
    $open = open (FH, "<", $file);
}
```

It is now opening case three above, and will fit the purposes of my assignment, despite it not being a solution that will work in broad cases.

Comment: relative file paths are fine, but are you asking how to locate "dir3" in a directory hierarchy?  Because you have at least two problems to resolve if that is your plan.  Do you start at the current relative path and look 'down' at child paths, start at the current relative path and work 'up' to parent paths (and then look down for each directory?) or start at the root and find a matching path vectory?

Comment: You might find multiple directories which match, and then you would need to check for matching subdirectories (you found 14 directories named dir3, which have a subdirectory named dir4?  and do any of those have a file named file.txt?)

Comment: Thanks for the comments Chuck.  My feeling is that with how the assignment was worded, I will be looking up to parent paths.  I have edited my post with a loop that seems to be working specific to my assignment.  I should have asked my professor earlier about how he would be testing case 3, but of course I put it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening `dir3/dir4/file.txt` will work fine if that's the correct path to the file.

```
>md "dir3"

>md "dir3/dir4"

>echo foo >"dir3/dir4/file.txt"

>perl -E"open(my $fh, '<', 'dir3/dir4/file.txt') or die($!); print <$fh>;"
foo
```

If it's not, then there's no way to know to what file it's referring without additional info.

---

Of course, that assumes the paths are relative to the current work directory. If those paths are relative to some other directory you can use the following:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );

my $fqfn = rel2abs($qfn, "/home/foo");
open(my $fh, '<', $fqfn) or die($!);
```

More specifically, if those paths are relative to the directory in which the script resides, you can use the following:

```
use FindBin               qw( $RealBin );
use File::Spec::Functions qw( rel2abs );

my $fqfn = rel2abs($qfn, $RealBin);
open(my $fh, '<', $fqfn) or die($!);
```

Comment: I believe this works because the current working directory would be dir2 in your example.  In my present case, my CWD is dir4.  Could I go into a loop that tried to open the file, and if open returned 0, cd ..?  Or rather, would that be a good way to do it?

Comment: How can you tell it's two levels up for `dir3/dir4/file.txt` and not for `file.txt`? There could easily be a `file.txt` at both locations, so how can you tell which is the correct one? Again, unless there's information you're not telling us, it's impossible. Use the right path.

Comment: In this specific case, I have control over the files in the directory tree, and I know that there is only one copy of "file.txt" that exists, in dir4.  I am going to accept your answer, as I'm sure it is correct and works in a majority of cases.  I am also going to edit my answer with a loop I wrote that seems very specific to the instructions I was given by my instructor.  Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to look and and loop down for the file. For looking up, just use `$new_path = Cwd::abs_path("$old_path/..")` until you hit the root directory, testing for the file using `open`. (If the file doesn't exist, `open` will return false and `$!{ENOENT}`) will be true. For looking down, you can use File::Find or the easier to use File::Find::Rule. (`File::Find::Rule->name("file.txt")->file->in(".")`)